# How can I obtain the average of students with non-failing subjects?

Tags: mysql

I have this data in the table:

```
id_student | Grade 
   1       |  8 
   2       | 10
   3       |  6-- Fail
   1       | 10
```

Each grade references to a different subject and the expected result should be:

```
id_student | AVG 
   1       |  9 
   2       | 10
```

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @scaisEdge, but instead of a subquery you use a conditional count to see how many fails grade have each student. Then only select the one with 0 fails.

```
select id_student, avg(grade)
from my_table
group by id_student
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN grade <= 6 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfect. You save my life. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a not in and a subselect (and obvious a group by for AVG)

```
select id_student, avg(grade)
from my_table
where id_student not in (select id_student 
            from my_table where grade <= 6)
group by id_student
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `where grade <= 6` in the subselect statement? or change `not in` to `in` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the query doesn't show me nothing. But the query of @Juan Carlos Oropeza works perfect. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(Grade) FROM TABLE WHERE Grade > 6
```

So this selects the avg of grades from your table (change the TABLE to your table name) where the grade is above the failing grade (I assume its 6 from your question)

Comment: This just remove the failing grade, OP want the students without failing grades.